# Narrowing down a type from function return types

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have a function which might return values of two different types, e.g. `Union[str, int]`. The type of the returned value can be determined from the function argument. So on each call, I know which type should be returned. However, mypy complains that `Union[str, int]` type cannot be assigned to a stricter type, e.g. `str`. Is there a way to allow stricter type assignment, without completely turning type checking off (e.g. with `# type: ignore` comment)?

For example, if I have this function:

```
from typing import Union


def change_value(action: str, value: int) -> Union[str, int]
    if action == "stringify":
        return str(value)
    return value

stringified_value: str
stringified_value = change_value("stringify", 10)
```

Mypy complains with this error:

```
Expression of type "str | int" cannot be assigned to declared type "str"
```

I would like to remove mypy error by somehow telling mypy, that in this case type narrowing down is always correct.

Comment: As I understand it, the issue is that the type `Union[str, int]` doesn't match the type of the variable returned, decalred as an `str`

Comment: @user12932966 Yes. The variable type is correctly declared as `str` and in this case function will always return `str`, even if the return type is `Union[str, int]`. And I want to make mypy to understand that.

Comment: Why would declare the return type as `Union[str, int]` if the function _always_ returns a string ? This looks like an inconsistency for me... Either it's always a string or is a union between str and int, both can't be true, stricto sensu.

Comment: It seems like what you actually want is _overloads_, so you can determine whether you're in the returns-int case or the returns-string case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought that you can use *overloads* only if the types of function arguments are different, not the values.

Comment: @user12932966 The return type can also be `int` if action is not `"stringify"`.

Comment: If you have a known group of `action` strings you could use `Literal`s, then the type _is_ different. Fundamentally MyPy is telling you the right thing - as far as the information you've given it, that assignment is **not** safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using overloads:

```py
from typing import Literal, Union, overload

@overload
def change_value(action: Literal['stringify'], value: int) -> str: ...
@overload
def change_value(action: Literal['whatever_else'], value: int) -> int: ...

def change_value(action: str, value: int) -> Union[str, int]:
    if action == "stringify":
        return str(value)
    return value

stringified_value: str = change_value("stringify", 10)
```

[playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=62786394f7544a55f8a961bbd813b816)

This approach has an additional benefit: you explicitly tell that `stringify` and `whatever_else` are two only possible actions, and call like `change_value('stingify', 2)` will be denied by type checker (noticed the typo? If not, it would be hard to debug otherwise).